# Address of local variables decrease in recursive function

Tags: c

While I was studying C programming, I found out that the address of a local variable that is stored in a stack will decrease and will go from higher addresses to lower addresses in a recursive function, every time the function is called recursively.

I want to know the reason for that. Why doesn't it increase sometimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory used for the “stack” of a program is conventionally used by starting at the high address in the memory and decreasing the address as more things are put on the stack. There is no logical requirement for this; we could just as easily start at the low address and put new things at increasing addresses. The convention is simply an artifact of history.

So, when you call a function, the new data for it—arguments being passed to it, the return address being saved, local variables for the function—are new on the stack, so they go into lower addresses.

(In fact, this arrangement is dangerous. If the function creates a buffer for input data on the stack and fails to guard against overflowing that buffer, excess data will go into higher addresses, corrupting older things on the stack, including the function’s return address. Malicious actors may exploit this by sending input data that overwrites the return address with a new address. Then, when the function returns, program control goes to the new address chosen by the malicious actors.

If the stack grew upward instead of downward, overflowing a buffer could only corrupt other variables in the current function. The return address would not be at risk.)